# Removendo "BC" de datas em Timestamp no Postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql

Olá, estou tentando remover o "BC" das datas do sql mas não estou conseguindo.

Faço o seguinte:

```
 SELECT CAST("regiaulaavul_dataInicio" AS date) FROM "RegistroAulaAvulsa"
```

E acaba por me retornar a data com um BC (Before Christ) na frente. Gostaria de removê-lo para comparar com a data atual, que não traz o BC. Fazer comparações entre ambas retorna resultado incorreto.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Obrigado,

Lucas Kunze.

Comment: Tente isso: `SELECT DATE_FORMAT(regiaulaavul_dataInicio, '%M %d, %Y') FROM RegistroAulaAvulsa`

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda, pesquisei algo compatível com o DATE_FORMAT para postgres e encontrei o to_char, então o converti para date e funcionou.

Comment: Que bom que ajudei, se possível poste a sua solução para auxiliar os próximos que tiverem essa dúvida

Answer (score 1):

Com a ajuda dos comentários e do stackoverflow foi possível encontrar a seguinte solução:
    `to_char("regiaulaavul_dataInicio"::date, 'YYYY-MM-DD')::date`

Primeiro foi feito uma conversão para o formato string e então para data, assim removendo o "BC" e permitindo comparar com outras datas.

> 1. Comentário do R.Santos
> 2. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12052705/date-format-in-postgresql